# My PHP functions not working on external server

Tags: php, function, session

I code site on my localhost "xampp" and everything was working super fine

Then i tried to test it on a free hosting but all functions and sessions not working

for example login.php not logged in and $_SESSION and functions on it not working

```
<?php
include ('core/coding/core.php');
check_log_in();
include ('panels/header.php');

?>
<title>Login</title>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      if (empty($username) === true or empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Enter all Fields';
      }
      else
        if (user_exists($username) === false) {
          $errors[] = 'Username not found.';
          $errors[] = 'Do You want to ' . '<a href="register.php">register</a>' . ' ?';
          $errors[] = 'Note That Username/Password are Case Senstive';
        }
        else
          if (user_active($username) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Account not Activated';
          }
          else
            if (strlen($password) > 32) {
              $errors[] = 'Password is too long';
            }
            else {
              $login = login($username, $password);
              if ($login === false) {
                $errors[] = 'Incorrect Information';
              }
              else {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=' . D_TEMPLATE . '">';
                die();
              }
      }
    }
    if (!empty($errors)) {
      echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 login">
        <center><h2>Login</h2></center>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" name="password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">login</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

core.php

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting();
ob_start();
include ('connect.php');
include ('general.php');
include ('function.php');
define('D_TEMPLATE', 'http://localhost/site');
$errors = array();
?>
```

The register.php too no functions works

I tried 3 different free hosting for now and the same problem .. so where is the problem there

Wish you can help me I can't sleep :(

Thanks

EDIT:

Solution : fuctions was using the connection of old localhost at xampp
When i fixed it it works well

Thanks all

Comment: It would be nice if you could make a PHP page with php_info() inside.

Comment: what i need to check there ?!

Comment: The difference between the loaded modules/libraries between your xampp and free host.

Comment: So... can I add that as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run **php_info();** on both servers and look for the difference in the modules/libraries loaded.